# PostgreSQL how to safely remove files inside pg_wal directory

Tags: postgresql

i have a legacy postgreSQL DB and the pg_wal size is very huge,
how to safely remove the early files inside pg_wal directory to reduce the pg_wal size without interrupting the current database?
Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. At the current state your question lacks a lot of information that could help us in providing a meaningful answer. What version of Postgres are you using? What type of Postgres installation are you using? Are you on Linux or Windows or Mac? Please provide additional information and clarification to extend your question, and to increase the likelihood of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no safe way to manually remove files in `pg_wal`. Don't do it.

You have to figure out the reason that keeps PostgreSQL from deleting the files. A stale replication slot? Is the archiver stuck? Is `wal_keep_size` (`wal_keep_segments` in older releases) large?

Once you have fixed the problem, the situation will gradually improve. WAL segments are automatically deleted during checkpoints.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, in current database there is replication ERROR in log file, how to ignore the replication and clean up the current pg_wal?

Comment: Drop the replication slot.

Comment: so after drop the replication, the pg_wal files will release by itself?

Comment: After dropping the replication *slot*, yes.